# Import Custom Work Item Type To ALL TFS Projects

Tags: customization

I've created a new Work Item type for use in our TFS 2010 setup and I can import into a single project fine, however, I'd like to import it to all existing Team Projects and have it immediately available in new Team Projects.

I've done this before, but on an old machine and now I can't remember how I did it so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute the

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:url /p:teamprojectname /f:filename
```

For more information, see the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx

Comment: This.  You'll just need to script this for each of your team projects.

Comment: I think we can loop it using PowerShell